# convert from Power to dBm in FPGA

Tags: fpga, verilog

I need to convert Power data coming out of my FFT->Cordic into dBm

I know the coefficient of my ADC and FFT and all I need is for every case of power coming to my block, to convert it to the right dBm value.

I do this by compare every range of values and for every rang eof values I output specific dBm value.

This is my working code:

```
module pw2dBm 
#(
    parameter IN_WIDTH = 28,
    parameter OUT_WIDTH = 8
)
(
    input                           clk,
    input                           rstn,
    input                           div,
    input       [IN_WIDTH-1:0]      din,

    output reg                      dov,
    output reg                      obe,
    output reg  [OUT_WIDTH-1:0]     dout
);


    reg                 div_r;
    reg  [IN_WIDTH-1:0] din_r;

    reg                 obe_f;  // output block end flag


    initial begin
        dov     = 1'b0;
        obe     = 1'b0;
        dout    = {OUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};

        div_r   = 1'b0;
        din_r   = {IN_WIDTH{1'b0}};
        obe_f   = 1'b0;
    end


    always @(posedge clk or negedge rstn) begin 
        if (~rstn) begin
            div_r   <= 1'b0;
            din_r   <= {IN_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            obe_f   <= 1'b0;
            obe     <= 1'b0;
        end else begin
            if (div) begin
                obe_f   <= 1'b1;
                obe     <= 1'b0;

                div_r   <= 1'b1;
                din_r   <= din;
            end else begin
                if (obe_f) begin
                    obe_f   <= 1'b0;
                    obe     <= 1'b1;
                end else begin
                    obe     <= 1'b0;
                end
                div_r   <= 1'b0;
                din_r   <= {IN_WIDTH{1'b0}};
            end
        end
    end

    function reg inbetween;
        input [IN_WIDTH-1:0] low; 
        input [IN_WIDTH-1:0] value; 
        input [IN_WIDTH-1:0] high; 
    begin
        inbetween = value >= low && value < high;
    end
    endfunction

    always @(posedge clk or negedge rstn) begin : lookup_table
        if (~rstn) begin
            dov     <= 1'b0;
            dout    <= {OUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
        end else if (div_r) begin
            dov     <= 1'b1;
            case(1) 
                inbetween(0, din_r, 1): dout <= 8'h00;  // -132.041 dBm
                inbetween(1, din_r, 2): dout <= 8'h01;  // -126.862 dBm
                inbetween(2, din_r, 3): dout <= 8'h02;  // -123.163 dBm
                inbetween(3, din_r, 4): dout <= 8'h03;  // -120.697 dBm
                inbetween(4, din_r, 5): dout <= 8'h04;  // -118.724 dBm
                inbetween(5, din_r, 6): dout <= 8'h05;  // -116.998 dBm
                inbetween(6, din_r, 7): dout <= 8'h06;  // -115.765 dBm
                inbetween(7, din_r, 8): dout <= 8'h07;  // -114.779 dBm
                inbetween(8, din_r, 9): dout <= 8'h08;  // -113.793 dBm
                inbetween(9, din_r, 10):    dout <= 8'h09;  // -112.806 dBm
                inbetween(10, din_r, 11):   dout <= 8'h0A;  // -111.820 dBm
                inbetween(11, din_r, 12):   dout <= 8'h0B;  // -111.080 dBm
                inbetween(12, din_r, 13):   dout <= 8'h0C;  // -110.340 dBm
                inbetween(13, din_r, 14):   dout <= 8'h0D;  // -109.600 dBm
                inbetween(14, din_r, 15):   dout <= 8'h0E;  // -109.107 dBm
                inbetween(15, din_r, 16):   dout <= 8'h0F;  // -108.614 dBm
                inbetween(16, din_r, 17):   dout <= 8'h10;  // -108.121 dBm
                inbetween(17, din_r, 18):   dout <= 8'h11;  // -107.628 dBm
                inbetween(18, din_r, 19):   dout <= 8'h12;  // -107.134 dBm
                inbetween(19, din_r, 20):   dout <= 8'h13;  // -106.641 dBm
                inbetween(20, din_r, 21):   dout <= 8'h14;  // -106.148 dBm
                inbetween(21, din_r, 23):   dout <= 8'h15;  // -105.655 dBm
                inbetween(23, din_r, 24):   dout <= 8'h16;  // -105.162 dBm
                inbetween(24, din_r, 26):   dout <= 8'h17;  // -104.668 dBm
                inbetween(26, din_r, 27):   dout <= 8'h18;  // -104.175 dBm
                inbetween(27, din_r, 29):   dout <= 8'h19;  // -103.682 dBm
                inbetween(29, din_r, 31):   dout <= 8'h1A;  // -103.189 dBm
                inbetween(31, din_r, 32):   dout <= 8'h1B;  // -102.696 dBm
                inbetween(32, din_r, 34):   dout <= 8'h1C;  // -102.202 dBm
                inbetween(34, din_r, 36):   dout <= 8'h1D;  // -101.709 dBm
                inbetween(36, din_r, 39):   dout <= 8'h1E;  // -101.216 dBm
                inbetween(39, din_r, 41):   dout <= 8'h1F;  // -100.723 dBm
                inbetween(41, din_r, 43):   dout <= 8'h20;  // -100.230 dBm
                inbetween(43, din_r, 46):   dout <= 8'h21;  // -99.736 dBm
                inbetween(46, din_r, 49):   dout <= 8'h22;  // -99.243 dBm
                inbetween(49, din_r, 52):   dout <= 8'h23;  // -98.750 dBm
                inbetween(52, din_r, 55):   dout <= 8'h24;  // -98.257 dBm
                inbetween(55, din_r, 58):   dout <= 8'h25;  // -97.764 dBm
                inbetween(58, din_r, 61):   dout <= 8'h26;  // -97.270 dBm
                inbetween(61, din_r, 65):   dout <= 8'h27;  // -96.777 dBm
                inbetween(65, din_r, 69):   dout <= 8'h28;  // -96.284 dBm
                inbetween(69, din_r, 73):   dout <= 8'h29;  // -95.791 dBm
                inbetween(73, din_r, 77):   dout <= 8'h2A;  // -95.298 dBm
                inbetween(77, din_r, 82):   dout <= 8'h2B;  // -94.804 dBm
                inbetween(82, din_r, 87):   dout <= 8'h2C;  // -94.311 dBm
                inbetween(87, din_r, 92):   dout <= 8'h2D;  // -93.818 dBm
                inbetween(92, din_r, 97):   dout <= 8'h2E;  // -93.325 dBm
                inbetween(97, din_r, 103):  dout <= 8'h2F;  // -92.832 dBm
                inbetween(103, din_r, 109): dout <= 8'h30;  // -92.338 dBm
                inbetween(109, din_r, 115): dout <= 8'h31;  // -91.845 dBm
                inbetween(115, din_r, 122): dout <= 8'h32;  // -91.352 dBm
                inbetween(122, din_r, 129): dout <= 8'h33;  // -90.859 dBm
                inbetween(129, din_r, 137): dout <= 8'h34;  // -90.366 dBm
                inbetween(137, din_r, 145): dout <= 8'h35;  // -89.872 dBm
                inbetween(145, din_r, 154): dout <= 8'h36;  // -89.379 dBm
                inbetween(154, din_r, 163): dout <= 8'h37;  // -88.886 dBm
                inbetween(163, din_r, 172): dout <= 8'h38;  // -88.393 dBm
                inbetween(172, din_r, 182): dout <= 8'h39;  // -87.900 dBm
                inbetween(182, din_r, 193): dout <= 8'h3A;  // -87.406 dBm
                inbetween(193, din_r, 205): dout <= 8'h3B;  // -86.913 dBm
                inbetween(205, din_r, 217): dout <= 8'h3C;  // -86.420 dBm
                inbetween(217, din_r, 229): dout <= 8'h3D;  // -85.927 dBm
                inbetween(229, din_r, 243): dout <= 8'h3E;  // -85.434 dBm
                inbetween(243, din_r, 257): dout <= 8'h3F;  // -84.940 dBm
                inbetween(257, din_r, 272): dout <= 8'h40;  // -84.447 dBm
                inbetween(272, din_r, 288): dout <= 8'h41;  // -83.954 dBm
                inbetween(288, din_r, 305): dout <= 8'h42;  // -83.461 dBm
                inbetween(305, din_r, 323): dout <= 8'h43;  // -82.968 dBm
                inbetween(323, din_r, 342): dout <= 8'h44;  // -82.474 dBm
                inbetween(342, din_r, 362): dout <= 8'h45;  // -81.981 dBm
                inbetween(362, din_r, 383): dout <= 8'h46;  // -81.488 dBm
                inbetween(383, din_r, 405): dout <= 8'h47;  // -80.995 dBm
                inbetween(405, din_r, 429): dout <= 8'h48;  // -80.502 dBm
                inbetween(429, din_r, 454): dout <= 8'h49;  // -80.009 dBm
                inbetween(454, din_r, 481): dout <= 8'h4A;  // -79.515 dBm
                inbetween(481, din_r, 509): dout <= 8'h4B;  // -79.022 dBm
                inbetween(509, din_r, 539): dout <= 8'h4C;  // -78.529 dBm
                inbetween(539, din_r, 570): dout <= 8'h4D;  // -78.036 dBm
                inbetween(570, din_r, 603): dout <= 8'h4E;  // -77.543 dBm
                inbetween(603, din_r, 639): dout <= 8'h4F;  // -77.049 dBm
                inbetween(639, din_r, 676): dout <= 8'h50;  // -76.556 dBm
                inbetween(676, din_r, 716): dout <= 8'h51;  // -76.063 dBm
                inbetween(716, din_r, 758): dout <= 8'h52;  // -75.570 dBm
                inbetween(758, din_r, 802): dout <= 8'h53;  // -75.077 dBm
                inbetween(802, din_r, 849): dout <= 8'h54;  // -74.583 dBm
                inbetween(849, din_r, 898): dout <= 8'h55;  // -74.090 dBm
                inbetween(898, din_r, 951): dout <= 8'h56;  // -73.597 dBm
                inbetween(951, din_r, 1007):    dout <= 8'h57;  // -73.104 dBm
                inbetween(1007, din_r, 1065):   dout <= 8'h58;  // -72.611 dBm
                inbetween(1065, din_r, 1128):   dout <= 8'h59;  // -72.117 dBm
                inbetween(1128, din_r, 1194):   dout <= 8'h5A;  // -71.624 dBm
                inbetween(1194, din_r, 1264):   dout <= 8'h5B;  // -71.131 dBm
                inbetween(1264, din_r, 1337):   dout <= 8'h5C;  // -70.638 dBm
                inbetween(1337, din_r, 1416):   dout <= 8'h5D;  // -70.145 dBm
                inbetween(1416, din_r, 1498):   dout <= 8'h5E;  // -69.651 dBm
                inbetween(1498, din_r, 1586):   dout <= 8'h5F;  // -69.158 dBm
                inbetween(1586, din_r, 1679):   dout <= 8'h60;  // -68.665 dBm
                inbetween(1679, din_r, 1777):   dout <= 8'h61;  // -68.172 dBm
                inbetween(1777, din_r, 1881):   dout <= 8'h62;  // -67.679 dBm
                inbetween(1881, din_r, 1991):   dout <= 8'h63;  // -67.185 dBm
                inbetween(1991, din_r, 2107):   dout <= 8'h64;  // -66.692 dBm
                inbetween(2107, din_r, 2230):   dout <= 8'h65;  // -66.199 dBm
                inbetween(2230, din_r, 2361):   dout <= 8'h66;  // -65.706 dBm
                inbetween(2361, din_r, 2498):   dout <= 8'h67;  // -65.213 dBm
                inbetween(2498, din_r, 2645):   dout <= 8'h68;  // -64.719 dBm
                inbetween(2645, din_r, 2799):   dout <= 8'h69;  // -64.226 dBm
                inbetween(2799, din_r, 2963):   dout <= 8'h6A;  // -63.733 dBm
                inbetween(2963, din_r, 3136):   dout <= 8'h6B;  // -63.240 dBm
                inbetween(3136, din_r, 3319):   dout <= 8'h6C;  // -62.747 dBm
                inbetween(3319, din_r, 3513):   dout <= 8'h6D;  // -62.253 dBm
                inbetween(3513, din_r, 3718):   dout <= 8'h6E;  // -61.760 dBm
                inbetween(3718, din_r, 3936):   dout <= 8'h6F;  // -61.267 dBm
                inbetween(3936, din_r, 4166):   dout <= 8'h70;  // -60.774 dBm
                inbetween(4166, din_r, 4409):   dout <= 8'h71;  // -60.281 dBm
                inbetween(4409, din_r, 4667):   dout <= 8'h72;  // -59.787 dBm
                inbetween(4667, din_r, 4939):   dout <= 8'h73;  // -59.294 dBm
                inbetween(4939, din_r, 5228):   dout <= 8'h74;  // -58.801 dBm
                inbetween(5228, din_r, 5534):   dout <= 8'h75;  // -58.308 dBm
                inbetween(5534, din_r, 5857):   dout <= 8'h76;  // -57.815 dBm
                inbetween(5857, din_r, 6199):   dout <= 8'h77;  // -57.321 dBm
                inbetween(6199, din_r, 6561):   dout <= 8'h78;  // -56.828 dBm
                inbetween(6561, din_r, 6945):   dout <= 8'h79;  // -56.335 dBm
                inbetween(6945, din_r, 7351):   dout <= 8'h7A;  // -55.842 dBm
                inbetween(7351, din_r, 7780):   dout <= 8'h7B;  // -55.349 dBm
                inbetween(7780, din_r, 8235):   dout <= 8'h7C;  // -54.855 dBm
                inbetween(8235, din_r, 8716):   dout <= 8'h7D;  // -54.362 dBm
                inbetween(8716, din_r, 9225):   dout <= 8'h7E;  // -53.869 dBm
                inbetween(9225, din_r, 9764):   dout <= 8'h7F;  // -53.376 dBm
                inbetween(9764, din_r, 10335):  dout <= 8'h80;  // -52.883 dBm
                inbetween(10335, din_r, 10939): dout <= 8'h81;  // -52.389 dBm
                inbetween(10939, din_r, 11578): dout <= 8'h82;  // -51.896 dBm
                inbetween(11578, din_r, 12254): dout <= 8'h83;  // -51.403 dBm
                inbetween(12254, din_r, 12970): dout <= 8'h84;  // -50.910 dBm
                inbetween(12970, din_r, 13728): dout <= 8'h85;  // -50.417 dBm
                inbetween(13728, din_r, 14530): dout <= 8'h86;  // -49.923 dBm
                inbetween(14530, din_r, 15379): dout <= 8'h87;  // -49.430 dBm
                inbetween(15379, din_r, 16278): dout <= 8'h88;  // -48.937 dBm
                inbetween(16278, din_r, 17229): dout <= 8'h89;  // -48.444 dBm
                inbetween(17229, din_r, 18236): dout <= 8'h8A;  // -47.951 dBm
                inbetween(18236, din_r, 19301): dout <= 8'h8B;  // -47.457 dBm
                inbetween(19301, din_r, 20429): dout <= 8'h8C;  // -46.964 dBm
                inbetween(20429, din_r, 21622): dout <= 8'h8D;  // -46.471 dBm
                inbetween(21622, din_r, 22886): dout <= 8'h8E;  // -45.978 dBm
                inbetween(22886, din_r, 24223): dout <= 8'h8F;  // -45.485 dBm
                inbetween(24223, din_r, 25638): dout <= 8'h90;  // -44.991 dBm
                inbetween(25638, din_r, 27136): dout <= 8'h91;  // -44.498 dBm
                inbetween(27136, din_r, 28722): dout <= 8'h92;  // -44.005 dBm
                inbetween(28722, din_r, 30400): dout <= 8'h93;  // -43.512 dBm
                inbetween(30400, din_r, 32176): dout <= 8'h94;  // -43.019 dBm
                inbetween(32176, din_r, 34056): dout <= 8'h95;  // -42.526 dBm
                inbetween(34056, din_r, 36046): dout <= 8'h96;  // -42.032 dBm
                inbetween(36046, din_r, 38152): dout <= 8'h97;  // -41.539 dBm
                inbetween(38152, din_r, 40381): dout <= 8'h98;  // -41.046 dBm
                inbetween(40381, din_r, 42740): dout <= 8'h99;  // -40.553 dBm
                inbetween(42740, din_r, 45237): dout <= 8'h9A;  // -40.060 dBm
                inbetween(45237, din_r, 47880): dout <= 8'h9B;  // -39.566 dBm
                inbetween(47880, din_r, 50677): dout <= 8'h9C;  // -39.073 dBm
                inbetween(50677, din_r, 53638): dout <= 8'h9D;  // -38.580 dBm
                inbetween(53638, din_r, 56772): dout <= 8'h9E;  // -38.087 dBm
                inbetween(56772, din_r, 60089): dout <= 8'h9F;  // -37.594 dBm
                inbetween(60089, din_r, 63600): dout <= 8'hA0;  // -37.100 dBm
                inbetween(63600, din_r, 67316): dout <= 8'hA1;  // -36.607 dBm
                inbetween(67316, din_r, 71249): dout <= 8'hA2;  // -36.114 dBm
                inbetween(71249, din_r, 75411): dout <= 8'hA3;  // -35.621 dBm
                inbetween(75411, din_r, 79817): dout <= 8'hA4;  // -35.128 dBm
                inbetween(79817, din_r, 84481): dout <= 8'hA5;  // -34.634 dBm
                inbetween(84481, din_r, 89416): dout <= 8'hA6;  // -34.141 dBm
                inbetween(89416, din_r, 94641): dout <= 8'hA7;  // -33.648 dBm
                inbetween(94641, din_r, 100170):    dout <= 8'hA8;  // -33.155 dBm
                inbetween(100170, din_r, 106022):   dout <= 8'hA9;  // -32.662 dBm
                inbetween(106022, din_r, 112217):   dout <= 8'hAA;  // -32.168 dBm
                inbetween(112217, din_r, 118773):   dout <= 8'hAB;  // -31.675 dBm
                inbetween(118773, din_r, 125712):   dout <= 8'hAC;  // -31.182 dBm
                inbetween(125712, din_r, 133057):   dout <= 8'hAD;  // -30.689 dBm
                inbetween(133057, din_r, 140831):   dout <= 8'hAE;  // -30.196 dBm
                inbetween(140831, din_r, 149059):   dout <= 8'hAF;  // -29.702 dBm
                inbetween(149059, din_r, 157768):   dout <= 8'hB0;  // -29.209 dBm
                inbetween(157768, din_r, 166985):   dout <= 8'hB1;  // -28.716 dBm
                inbetween(166985, din_r, 176741):   dout <= 8'hB2;  // -28.223 dBm
                inbetween(176741, din_r, 187067):   dout <= 8'hB3;  // -27.730 dBm
                inbetween(187067, din_r, 197997):   dout <= 8'hB4;  // -27.236 dBm
                inbetween(197997, din_r, 209565):   dout <= 8'hB5;  // -26.743 dBm
                inbetween(209565, din_r, 221808):   dout <= 8'hB6;  // -26.250 dBm
                inbetween(221808, din_r, 234768):   dout <= 8'hB7;  // -25.757 dBm
                inbetween(234768, din_r, 248484):   dout <= 8'hB8;  // -25.264 dBm
                inbetween(248484, din_r, 263001):   dout <= 8'hB9;  // -24.770 dBm
                inbetween(263001, din_r, 278367):   dout <= 8'hBA;  // -24.277 dBm
                inbetween(278367, din_r, 294631):   dout <= 8'hBB;  // -23.784 dBm
                inbetween(294631, din_r, 311844):   dout <= 8'hBC;  // -23.291 dBm
                inbetween(311844, din_r, 330064):   dout <= 8'hBD;  // -22.798 dBm
                inbetween(330064, din_r, 349348):   dout <= 8'hBE;  // -22.304 dBm
                inbetween(349348, din_r, 369758):   dout <= 8'hBF;  // -21.811 dBm
                inbetween(369758, din_r, 391361):   dout <= 8'hC0;  // -21.318 dBm
                inbetween(391361, din_r, 414226):   dout <= 8'hC1;  // -20.825 dBm
                inbetween(414226, din_r, 438427):   dout <= 8'hC2;  // -20.332 dBm
                inbetween(438427, din_r, 464042):   dout <= 8'hC3;  // -19.838 dBm
                inbetween(464042, din_r, 491154):   dout <= 8'hC4;  // -19.345 dBm
                inbetween(491154, din_r, 519849):   dout <= 8'hC5;  // -18.852 dBm
                inbetween(519849, din_r, 550221):   dout <= 8'hC6;  // -18.359 dBm
                inbetween(550221, din_r, 582367):   dout <= 8'hC7;  // -17.866 dBm
                inbetween(582367, din_r, 616392):   dout <= 8'hC8;  // -17.372 dBm
                inbetween(616392, din_r, 652404):   dout <= 8'hC9;  // -16.879 dBm
                inbetween(652404, din_r, 690521):   dout <= 8'hCA;  // -16.386 dBm
                inbetween(690521, din_r, 730864):   dout <= 8'hCB;  // -15.893 dBm
                inbetween(730864, din_r, 773565):   dout <= 8'hCC;  // -15.400 dBm
                inbetween(773565, din_r, 818760):   dout <= 8'hCD;  // -14.906 dBm
                inbetween(818760, din_r, 866595):   dout <= 8'hCE;  // -14.413 dBm
                inbetween(866595, din_r, 917226):   dout <= 8'hCF;  // -13.920 dBm
                inbetween(917226, din_r, 970814):   dout <= 8'hD0;  // -13.427 dBm
                inbetween(970814, din_r, 1027534):  dout <= 8'hD1;  // -12.934 dBm
                inbetween(1027534, din_r, 1087567): dout <= 8'hD2;  // -12.440 dBm
                inbetween(1087567, din_r, 1151107): dout <= 8'hD3;  // -11.947 dBm
                inbetween(1151107, din_r, 1218360): dout <= 8'hD4;  // -11.454 dBm
                inbetween(1218360, din_r, 1289542): dout <= 8'hD5;  // -10.961 dBm
                inbetween(1289542, din_r, 1364883): dout <= 8'hD6;  // -10.468 dBm
                inbetween(1364883, din_r, 1444626): dout <= 8'hD7;  // -9.974 dBm
                inbetween(1444626, din_r, 1529027): dout <= 8'hD8;  // -9.481 dBm
                inbetween(1529027, din_r, 1618360): dout <= 8'hD9;  // -8.988 dBm
                inbetween(1618360, din_r, 1712912): dout <= 8'hDA;  // -8.495 dBm
                inbetween(1712912, din_r, 1812988): dout <= 8'hDB;  // -8.002 dBm
                inbetween(1812988, din_r, 1918911): dout <= 8'hDC;  // -7.509 dBm
                inbetween(1918911, din_r, 2031022): dout <= 8'hDD;  // -7.015 dBm
                inbetween(2031022, din_r, 2149683): dout <= 8'hDE;  // -6.522 dBm
                inbetween(2149683, din_r, 2275277): dout <= 8'hDF;  // -6.029 dBm
                inbetween(2275277, din_r, 2408209): dout <= 8'hE0;  // -5.536 dBm
                inbetween(2408209, din_r, 2548908): dout <= 8'hE1;  // -5.043 dBm
                inbetween(2548908, din_r, 2697826): dout <= 8'hE2;  // -4.549 dBm
                inbetween(2697826, din_r, 2855445): dout <= 8'hE3;  // -4.056 dBm
                inbetween(2855445, din_r, 3022273): dout <= 8'hE4;  // -3.563 dBm
                inbetween(3022273, din_r, 3198848): dout <= 8'hE5;  // -3.070 dBm
                inbetween(3198848, din_r, 3385739): dout <= 8'hE6;  // -2.577 dBm
                inbetween(3385739, din_r, 3583549): dout <= 8'hE7;  // -2.083 dBm
                inbetween(3583549, din_r, 3792916): dout <= 8'hE8;  // -1.590 dBm
                inbetween(3792916, din_r, 4014515): dout <= 8'hE9;  // -1.097 dBm
                inbetween(4014515, din_r, 4249061): dout <= 8'hEA;  // -0.604 dBm
                inbetween(4249061, din_r, 4497310): dout <= 8'hEB;  // -0.111 dBm
                inbetween(4497310, din_r, 4760063): dout <= 8'hEC;  // 0.383 dBm
                inbetween(4760063, din_r, 5038167): dout <= 8'hED;  // 0.876 dBm
                inbetween(5038167, din_r, 5332519): dout <= 8'hEE;  // 1.369 dBm
                inbetween(5332519, din_r, 5644069): dout <= 8'hEF;  // 1.862 dBm
                inbetween(5644069, din_r, 5973820): dout <= 8'hF0;  // 2.355 dBm
                inbetween(5973820, din_r, 6322838): dout <= 8'hF1;  // 2.849 dBm
                inbetween(6322838, din_r, 6692246): dout <= 8'hF2;  // 3.342 dBm
                inbetween(6692246, din_r, 7083237): dout <= 8'hF3;  // 3.835 dBm
                inbetween(7083237, din_r, 7497071): dout <= 8'hF4;  // 4.328 dBm
                inbetween(7497071, din_r, 7935083): dout <= 8'hF5;  // 4.821 dBm
                inbetween(7935083, din_r, 8398686): dout <= 8'hF6;  // 5.315 dBm
                inbetween(8398686, din_r, 8889375): dout <= 8'hF7;  // 5.808 dBm
                inbetween(8889375, din_r, 9408732): dout <= 8'hF8;  // 6.301 dBm
                inbetween(9408732, din_r, 9958432): dout <= 8'hF9;  // 6.794 dBm
                inbetween(9958432, din_r, 10540248):    dout <= 8'hFA;  // 7.287 dBm
                inbetween(10540248, din_r, 11156056):   dout <= 8'hFB;  // 7.781 dBm
                inbetween(11156056, din_r, 11807843):   dout <= 8'hFC;  // 8.274 dBm
                inbetween(11807843, din_r, 12497710):   dout <= 8'hFD;  // 8.767 dBm
                inbetween(12497710, din_r, 13227881):   dout <= 8'hFE;  // 9.260 dBm
                inbetween(13227881, din_r, 268435455):  dout <= 8'hFF;  // 9.753 dBm                    
            endcase
        end else begin
            dov     <= 1'b0;
            dout    <= {OUT_WIDTH{1'b0}};
        end
    end
endmodule
```

my question is how can I make this code more efficent? 
This block in my project is my biggest problem with Fmax, it makes something like 10-11ns delay path.
I need somehow to make it twice efficent.

I need somehow to pipeline it, but I dont really knwo to make it right.
any ideas or help about it?
what is the best algorithm to calculate dBm in FPGA?
there is a way to make my code more efficent?

Thanks!!

Comment: Where is `inbetween` defined?

Comment: further up in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm very surprised you came up with this incredibly complex code! This looks like you wanted to `if/else if` in an imperative language.

Good news: your FPGA is not a sequential CPU, there's no advantage to doing it this way. Just approximate the logarithm to a degree that your application considers exact. Hint: 8 bits in range for logarithmic values is **a lot**, and actually much more than the actual dynamic range of your system in default parametrication: your input is 28 bits wide (that's already a lot!) so your whole dynamic range between the smallest possible power value (1) and the largest possible power value (2²⁸) is only 10^(8.4). Not quite sure you gain much by having about 30 steps per decibel...

First of all: no use that you do it with logarithms to the base 10 – doing it with logarithms to the base 2 is much handier in binary systems, and in the end, you can just, instead of multiplying with 10 to go from log to dB, you'd multiply by 10·log10(2), a constant that isn't any different to your multiplication.

So, how to logarithm-base-2?

I'd actually try to pipeline that right away. Something like this C code (from [bit twiddling hacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog))

```
unsigned int v;          // 32-bit value to find the log2 of 
register unsigned int r; // result of log2(v) will go here
register unsigned int shift;

r =     (v > 0xFFFF) << 4; v >>= r;
shift = (v > 0xFF  ) << 3; v >>= shift; r |= shift;
shift = (v > 0xF   ) << 2; v >>= shift; r |= shift;
shift = (v > 0x3   ) << 1; v >>= shift; r |= shift;
                                        r |= (v >> 1);
```

You'll notice that if you just introduce a new  register `v_1`, `v_2` and so on, and the same for `r`, (and one `wire shift_N` for each stage), for every line in above code, you end up with something that is a pipelined recipe for a log2.

So, that's it! A four-stage that needs nothing but four integer comparisons with \$2^N-1\$, which is really just a bunch of ORs on the upper bits. Should use way less space than your huge set of comparisons, and also, has a nearly minimal combinatorial depth – relevant if you're going for high clock speeds.

Finally: You're not the first one to convert powers to decibel-of-unit, see tnt's `logpwr` [module](https://github.com/EttusResearch/fpga/blob/master/usrp3/lib/rfnoc/fosphor/f15_logpwr.v). He's done that to achieve this Realtime Spectrum-Analyzer alike display (with a few more features, like "digital phosphor", ie. slow fading out of bursty peaks etc):

[image: RFNoC fosphor]

You'll want to watch his [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ey9W2CUZKRs) from [GRCon'15] ([slides](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/543ae9afe4b0c3b808d72acd/t/55df1335e4b0b8c9e8ed55a1/1440682805606/2-munaut_sylvain-rfnoc_fosphor-2015-08-27.pdf)); here's a [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLFmPFpMwJs) of it running realtime.